# https шифрует трафик только от клиента к серверу?

Tags: веб-сервер, https

https шифрует трафик только от клиента к серверу?

Как я понимаю, сервер передает открытый ключ браузеру, которым шифруется исходящий трафик от клиента, а закрытым ключом на сервере расшифровывается.Какими же ключами шифруется и расшифровывается трафик от сервера к клиенту?

Comment: @ichoose, Если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

> сервер передает открытый ключ браузеру которым шифруется исходящий трафик от клиента, а закрытым ключом на сервере расшифровывается

Таки да. Подробнее смотрите [тут](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS)

Comment: а что же на счет входящего трафика, трафик с сервера не шифруется?

Answer (score 2):

https шифрует трафик в обоих направлениях, иначе не считали бы его безопасным.  после получения сертификата от сервера браузер придумывает случайное число и безопасным образом посылает его на сервер.  это позволяет создать ключ для шифрования дальнейшего обмена данными так, что он не может быть подсмотрен.   после этого все данные https идут по шифру.