# Как HTTPS трафик кэшируется на прокси-серверах? Ведь он же зашифрован

Tags: http, https, proxy

Или HTTPS трафик не кэшируется в общих кэшах (shared caches)?

То что HTTPS трафик шифруется в обоих направлениях очевидно. Вопрос о том как он кэшируется в общих кэшах будучи зашифрованным.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [https шифрует трафик только от клиента к серверу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/342793/https-%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83)

Comment: Смотря какой прокси. Если это web-прокси, указанный в соответствующих настройках браузера, то клиент знает о его наличии и сам не пытается установить соединение с сервером назначения и контролировать его сертификаты. Фактически клиент может зашифровать трафик ключом прокси, а сам прокси расшифрует его и зашифрует уже ключем сервера и конечно он будет видеть весь трафик и сможет его кешировать. А вот прозрачные (transparent) прокси разумеется не могут видеть содержимое и кешировать его для https

Comment: @Vadizar Вопрос о другом. То что HTTPS трафик шифруется в обоих направлениях очевидно. Вопрос о том как он кэшируется в общих кэшах будучи зашифрованным.

Comment: @Mike Я не нашёл никаких web-прокси в настройках браузера.

Comment: в гугле вбейте "браузер настройки прокси". Все прокси, которые не Socks - это web-прокси. И если вы не знаете где они в настройках, то о каких тогда прокси ваш вопрос ?

Comment: Всё очень просто: трафик шифруется самим прокси-сервером. Но тогда он должен владеть правильным сертификатом, естественно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если прокси "честный" (не подменяет сертификаты, что бы прослушивать трафик), то он не сможет закешировать трафик.

При TLS рукопожатии каждый раз создаются новые ключи, и даже если клиент и сервер обмениваются одними и теми же данными, со стороны это будет выглядеть как совершенно другой трафик. Если TLS использует старую сессию (со старыми ключами), трафик все равно будет выглядеть по-другому, так как IV генерируются случайно каждый раз. В конце концов, прокси не видит даже какой ресурс запрашивает клиент `index.html` или `logo.jpg`.